# Why specific file directory fails to redirect but its parent folder succeeds?

Tags: redirect, htaccess, rewrite-rules, 404-error, cache

I activated multisite using subdirectories on my old WordPress site, and I created a new site (say `my-example.com/new-site/`).

I found links such as `my-example.com/new-site/wp-content/mu-plugins/css/` can redirect to `my-example.com/wp-content/mu-plugins/css/`, however, `my-example.com/new-site/wp-content/mu-plugins/css/style.css` won't redirect and will throw out a 404 error, this leads to the site loading errors.

I was so confused, and tried hard refreshing sites, clearing cookies, but it didn't work.

The `.htaccess` file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: "`my-example.com/new-site/wp-content/mu-plugins/css/` can redirect to `my-example.com/wp-content/mu-plugins/css/`" - I'm not sure what you mean by that? There should be no "redirect" occurring here?

Comment: @MrWhite According to rule `RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]`, the redirect will occur.

Answer (score 1):

After trying a million of ways, I contacted the super admin and asked for permission to log into WP Engine, our host. I found there is a Multisite setting too. So I clicked "convert to multisite", and, bang! the error is resolved. Subsites can work properly now.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I wonder what that "magic switch" did?

Comment: @MrWhite I guess it has something to do with the Nginx reverse proxy, which may override my .htaccess redirect for .css/.js static files and causes error for loading those files. Setting multisite on WP Engine may alter the setting of Nginx and make it work.